# how to pass ListBox values back to controller in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

how to pass ListBox values back to controller in ASP.NET MVC 2  without using ViewData .
I have a listbox on ASP.NET MVC View . When submitting form I want to pass ListBox values back to controller . How to achieve this using Jquery or Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple . Use FormCollection in your Parameter list of Action method in your controller and then create a String Array for your ListBox values in your model .

Now Assign 
        formvalue["Your_ListBox_value"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

to your newly created String Array in your Controller .